# Action for changing the color of layer?

Tags: cocos2d-x

My game consists of a single scene which is a LayerColor. However, as I transition between "levels", I would like to change the background color via a smooth transition.

For example, if the
 rgb values of level 1 is (100,50,70) , and the
 rgb values of level 2 is (200,30,123).

Over a period of a few seconds, I would like to slowly modify the rgb values of the layer color from the level 1 value to the level 2 value.

Is it possible to do this using a cocos2d action ?

EDIT:

I do not wan't to tint all the children of my layer.
My scene is of type layer color:

```
class MyScene : public cocos2d::LayerColor
```

In Init I set the color:

```
bool MyScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !LayerColor::initWithColor(Color4B(10, 20, 200, 255) )) {
        return false;
    } ....
```

I don't wan't to tint the entire scene. I only want to change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cocos2d::TintTo` action:

```
auto layer = cocos2d::LayerColor::create(cocos2d::Color4B(100, 50, 70, 255));
...
layer->runAction(cocos2d::TintTo::create(2.0, 200, 30, 123));
```

Comment: Sorry - I guess I wasn't clear. I don't want to tint the entire scene and all the children. I just want to change the background color.

Comment: `cocos2d::LayerColor::setColor` doesn't change color of it's children, unless You called layer->setCascadeColorEnabled(true);